# Error while Retrieving First Party Audience Segmentations in GoogleAds Python Library [ServerError.SERVER_ERROR @ ]'

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I've encountered an error while attempting to list all first-party audience segmentations created in my GoogleAds account using the googleads Python library. Despite confirming that the credentials are correct and updating the library to the latest version available, I continue to face the following error:

[WARNING] 2024-03-26T12:42:30.368Z 41d1f691-e863-47a7-97c7-4ceec141ccef Error summary: {'faultMessage': '[ServerError.SERVER_ERROR @ ]', 'requestId': '8e056b59b2549571b78c96c177a495e2', 'responseTime': '1173', 'serviceName': 'AudienceSegmentService', 'methodName': 'getAudienceSegmentsByStatement'}

I've even attempted to execute the code on a clean installation in a virtual machine, but the error persists.

I'm reaching out to seek assistance from the community regarding this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards;

I've even attempted to execute the code on a clean installation in a virtual machine, but the error persists.

The credentials are correct.